# Creating Iphone API for Aweber?

Tags: php, objective-c, api, ios4

I have to create a iphone app using Aweber. But Aweber has no iphone API [link](https://labs.aweber.com/). Now I just want to know that I have knowledge of PHP and aweber has PHP API, is it possible to create a iphone API for a newbie like me  (I mean for Iphone) to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a special iPhone API, you would use Objective-C to consume the Aweber API the same as you would use PHP, Ruby, Java, Python or any other language to consume the API for a web app.

The Aweber API is REST based so you can look at http://restkit.org/. From their website "RestKit is an Objective-C framework for iOS that aims to make interacting with RESTful web services simple".

If Objective-C isn't your thing, their is Titanium from Appcelerator, you use JavaScript to build your app and it gets compiled into Objective-C. Mobile Tuts has a nice tutorial on how to consume the Twitter API, which is also REST based. It should give you a good foundation to get you started.
(http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/appcelerator/appcelerator-using-json-to-build-a-twitter-client/)

Comment: require_once('aweber_api/aweber_api.php'); how can i do this  in c# or c objective

Answer (score 0):

I am not signing up for an account so I don't know exactly how the API works, but if I were setting up an iPhone App to work with this, I would use the rails plugin.  Rails gives you JSON communication for free (IE no extra work required) http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html see section 2.2.9. Then use on IOS app use something like: http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/  to interact with that.

Answer (score 0):

the iPhone does not have a fixed API reader, you can write your own,

http://www.aweber.com/faq/questions/200/Does+AWeber+Have+an+API%3F

The system has an API so there is no work that needs to be done for the system, just your app an API is an Application Programming(or some times known as plugin) Interface,

by reading that page it tells me they have an XML for which iOS libs have a parser built all ready so you can use that,

if your building the app, i would recommend looking at phone gap then your using JavaScript to control the API so alot simpler to work with,

And just a correction on your question they will not have a php API what they will have is a php library for talking to there API server,

https://labs.aweber.com/docs/reference/1.0 this link will provide you with the all the API calls you need to work with it's using JSON so php uses json_decode function to get the data from there servers,

Javascript within PhoneGap can call it without a problem from the phone.